# Array variable in structure overwritten

Tags: vb.net

I have an address program for envelopes which reads info from a text file.  The file is read line by line and names and addresses are assigned to a variable called "tempaddr" which is then added to a List (of nameaddress) variable called "address".

See code excerpt below:

```
Public Structure nameaddress
    Friend name As String
    Friend addressline() As String
    Friend contact As String

    Public Sub initialize()
        ReDim addressline(3)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear()
        name = ""
        Array.Clear(addressline, 0, 3)
        contact = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(ByVal na As nameaddress)
        With na
            name = .name
            addressline = .addressline
            .contact = .contact
        End With
    End Sub
End Structure

Public address As New List(Of nameaddress)
Public tempaddr As New nameaddress
.
.
.
address.Add(tempaddr)
```

The problem is that the name and contact variables are assigned OK but the addressline() variable is overwritten on all previous entries in the "address" list.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have left out the important part of your code, the loop that reads the names and addresses from the file. However, I suspect that the problem is that you are declaring the tempaddr variable outside that loop. That means that every time you add tempaddr to to the address list, you are adding another reference to the same object. In that case, the answer is to declare tempaddr inside the loop and create a new instance of it each time you read a line from the file.